# Alternatives to looping in Pandas when you need to update a column based on another

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have a `Pandas` `dataframe` with text dates that'd I like to convert to `datetime`. The problem is some of my text dates are bad data and thus can't be converted. In cases for which a date can't be converted, I want to update an `Error` column to a value of `True` as well as set the `Date` column to `None` so that it can later be added to a database column that is formatted as a `datetime`.

This is a simplified example. My `dataframe` may have 1 million rows and multiple date columns this needs to be done for, so I need a faster way of doing this. I know the typical convention is to avoid looping with `Pandas`, but I can't figure out a way around it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

data = 1000 *[['010115', None],
        ['320115', None]]


df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,
                  columns=['Date', 'Error'])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Date'], '%d%m%y')
    except ValueError:
        row['Date'] = None
        row['Error'] = True
    except TypeError:
        pass

print df
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` and [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html):

```
data = 10 *[['010115', None],
        ['320115', None]]


df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,
                  columns=['Date', 'Error'])

print (df)
      Date Error
0   010115  None
1   320115  None
2   010115  None
3   320115  None
4   010115  None
5   320115  None
6   010115  None
7   320115  None
8   010115  None
9   320115  None
10  010115  None
11  320115  None
12  010115  None
13  320115  None
14  010115  None
15  320115  None
16  010115  None
17  320115  None
18  010115  None
19  320115  None
```

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d%m%y',errors='coerce') 
df['Error'] = df['Date'].isnull()
print (df)
         Date  Error
0  2015-01-01  False
1         NaT   True
2  2015-01-01  False
3         NaT   True
4  2015-01-01  False
5         NaT   True
6  2015-01-01  False
7         NaT   True
8  2015-01-01  False
9         NaT   True
10 2015-01-01  False
11        NaT   True
12 2015-01-01  False
13        NaT   True
14 2015-01-01  False
15        NaT   True
16 2015-01-01  False
17        NaT   True
18 2015-01-01  False
19        NaT   True
```

Comment: Is necessary convert `NaT` to `None` ?

Comment: I'll have to trying pushing to the database. I think it will recognize that as a `Null`/`None` value so probably not. Just to clarify `NaT` is Not a Time?

Comment: Yes, it is Not a Time.

Comment: Is there a way to differential your `NaT` from `NaN` if it was missing in the original data set?

Comment: No, it is same. It is `NaN` for `Datetime`.

Comment: @Jerzrael How would you suggest I seperate Dates that come from a file with no data and the ones that become `NaT`?

Comment: Hmmm, do you need data with `NaT` ? Do you need split output to `2` `DataFrames` - with `NaT` and with `not NaT` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121784/discussion-between-user2242044-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 2):

You can skip the initial creation of `df` and construct it from the specific columns you need instead.

```
# I push a list of first elements from data via a comprehension
dates = pd.to_datetime([d[0] for d in data], format='%d%m%y', errors='coerce')

# Construct df from scratch here
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dates})
df['Error'] = df.Date.isnull()
df.head()
```

[image]

---

#### Timing

This is the difference between using an already constructed `df` versus building it from scratch

[image]

Comment: @AlbertoGarcia-Raboso I've updated my answer.  As you can see, The main point of differentiation between your's and jezreal's answer is that you leveraged the dataframe the OP already created.  I'm trying to make the point that creating a full dataframe only to overwrite its contents is inefficient.